# Word-initial consonant clusters beginning with /s/ or /ʃ/, an Indo-European characteristic?

Tags: indo-european, pronunciation

All the cases I've seen  of a consonant /s/ (or similar pronunciations) at the beginning of a word occur in Indo-European languages. Can we say that this is a characteristic of this language family?

/s/ +  some consonant

/ʃ/ + some consonant

*Examples:*
star(english), ster(dutch),  strana(russian) schnell (german), stamina(latin), spyros (greek),...

Comment: There are many non-IE languages that have word-initial /s/, such as Arabic (e.g. *silsila* - 'chain'). /s/ is a fairly frequent consonant among the world's languages.

Comment: It looks like the poster is talking about /sC/ consonant clusters, but I can only guess.

Comment: @ robert, I'm asking about /s/+ some consonant or /sh/+ some consonant (I don't know how to use phonetic notations here)

Comment: I see, /s/+ plosive or /ʃ/+ plosive (*star*, *strana*, *spyros*) are unusual (or 'marked') because they do not obey the [Sonority Sequencing Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonority_Sequencing_Principle). Fricatives (such as /s/) are more sonorous than the following plosives, but word-initially sonority should rise towards the syllable nucleus. Because the Sonority Sequencing Principle is by and large obeyed by most languages I'd expect /s/+ plosive or /ʃ/+ plosive to be relatively unusual (but probably not exclusive to Indo-European).

Comment: Is "Indo-European characteristic" intended to mean "phenomenon restricted to IE"? If so, the answer is no: lots of non-IE languages have such clusters.

Comment: In [Lushootseed](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Lushootseed.html) something like 2/3 of the nouns start with /s/, generally before a consonant, because roots are normally CVC and _s-_ is a nominalizing prefix. Of course consonant clusters are the norm in Lushootseed -- plenty of words have 4- or 5-consonant clusters, some of which get reduplicated.

Comment: I think you are asking about sibilant + consonant clusters, not about initial sibilants. Am I right? If so, do you think you could reformulate the question?

Comment: s+stop cluster also appears in Cherokee language. stááya (hard), skwíísti (a lot).

Answer (score 2):

Indeed in the Proto-Indo-European language there is a known [phenomenon called "s-mobile"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indo-European_s-mobile). Some roots in PIE could occasionally have an initial augment "s-". Since all PIE roots begin with a consonant, this gives initial "sC-" cluster. The meaning of this extension is not known. We only know that some words with a root had it while others did not.

There is a theory that this initial s- could be result of fusion between the usual PIE ending -s/-os with the following word.

But most of the examples you gave are irrelevant.

The word for star in PIE was ***a̯ster***, with the first phoneme being a laryngeal which was either lost or became a vowel. It is conjectured that the initial form was even more complicated: ***a̯e̯ster*** and related to ***a̯ee̯tr***, "fire".

Russian "strana" on the other hand, sometimes considered to derive from a root with s-mobile "(s)tero̯-" ([Pokorny](http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/response.cgi?root=config&morpho=0&basename=%5Cdata%5Cie%5Cpokorny&first=1&off=&text_root=%28s%29ter-1&method_root=substring&text_meaning=&method_meaning=substring&ic_meaning=on&text_ger_mean=&method_ger_mean=substring&ic_ger_mean=on&text_grammar=&method_grammar=substring&ic_grammar=on&text_comments=&method_comments=substring&ic_comments=on&text_derivative=&method_derivative=substring&ic_derivative=on&text_material=&method_material=substring&ic_material=on&text_ref=&method_ref=substring&ic_ref=on&text_seealso=&method_seealso=substring&ic_seealso=on&text_pages=&method_pages=substring&ic_pages=on&text_any=&method_any=substring&sort=number&ic_any=on)) which meant "stretch" but this root may be considered s-mobile erroneously due mixing with other roots (Starling gives this root with a solid s).

The origin of the "schnell" and "snell" is unknown beyond Proto-Germanic.

The word "stamina" origins from the root "stea̯-" which had no mobile "s" at least in the observable PIE stage.

The origin of the "spyros" is also unknown.

Comment: I don't think this addresses the question -- the poster isn't asking about the etymology of sC- clusters but about their synchronic worldwide distribution.

Answer (score -3):

s-mobile can be taken as a natural widespread environmental sound, therefore existing before human oral language came to life, and then used - or not used - 'also' to strengthen or underline the basic sounds of the "sound-system" which originated proto-language phonemes, in a time where no grammar and no word division could exist or play any major role ... see the word 'stone' as a 's-mobile' plus 'tone', whose initial consonant comes to underline the 'sound effect' of the word 'tone', being the whole mix the resulting effect of the reproduction of natural sounds (the object called 'stone' hitting something or someone).
Giuseppe Maiorano
 -> see academia-edu, g.maiorano, "The voice ot things, etc."